# Ranking of data that have the most data points in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, data-analysis

I would like to look at the top 10 products that have the most corresponding data points by date.
Since the quantity sold in a day is recorded under "soldUnits", there are no duplicate entries for an ArticleNr at one date.
The maximum number in the example dataset would therefore be "365 obs. of 3 variables".
How can I filter my dataset?

**Edit:** With the edited dataset given, I want to filter out Article Nr "1" because it has the most corresponding data in column "Date"

The problem in my real data is that there are around 2000 Products and I can't see what Article Nr has the most corresponding data in column "Date"

**Edit2:**
As a MRE we can look at this Dataset

```
df <- data.frame(ArticleNr = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1"),
                created = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"), "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT"),
                soldUnits = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

That leads to

```
   ArticleNr soldDate      soldUnits
     11      2020-01-01         1   
     22      2020-01-01         1   
     33      2020-01-01         1   
     11      2020-01-02         1   
     22      2020-01-02         1   
     11      2020-01-03         1
```

My desired result would be a ranking with n-ranks (Top 3, Top 10, Top 25)

In this Dataframe it would look like this

```
   Rank  ArticleNr  soldOnDates     
     1     11         3         #<-- ArticleNr 11 was sold on 3 out of 3 days, so it has Rank 1 
     2     22         2   
     3     33         1
```

How can I achieve this on a big dataset with around 2000 products?

Comment: In your example data, which "products (...) have the most data points by date"? It seems that both dates have four different `Article Nr` which each appear once. Can you adjust your example data to demonstrate what you want to do?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of a table. You can also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase your chances of getting an answer. And show your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to @Pa_Syl answer that uses table(). As an added bonus, you can use your own column names instead of Var1 and Freq. The part after summarise() is needed to calculate the rank of each ArticleNr.

```
df %>% group_by(ArticleNr) %>% summarise(SoldOnDate = n()) %>%
 ungroup() %>% arrange(-SoldOnDate) %>% mutate(rank = 1:n())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking too abstractly and did not see the most obvious and easiest solution.
In my example I have now proceeded in such a way that I have determined the frequency of the occurrence of an `ArticleNr`.

If each `ArticleNr` can occur only once a day, it is enough to determine the frequency without taking the detour and to determine a ranking which refers to `ArticleNr` and `Date`.

My solution is:

```
table(df$ArticleNr) %>% 
        as.data.frame() %>% 
        arrange(desc(Freq))
```